# Property set in react.cloneElement undefined type error on unmount react

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a react component that adds properties to children on mount using `React.cloneElement`. Everything works fine until the component unmounts via conditional render, then it throws a typeError and crashes. Any idea why?

Here is the render block

```js
render() {
    const inputs = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
        React.cloneElement(child, {
            value: this.state.value,
            onChange: this.onChange,
            error: this.state.userNotify[child.props.name]
        })
    );
    return (
        <div id="form-container">
            <p className="formTitle">{this.props.formTitle}</p>
            <form id={this.props.formID} onSubmit={this.onSubmit} >
                {inputs} {/*there must be nested input components passed in*/}
            </form>
        </div>
    )
};
```

After submitting the form, the component is unmounted with a conditional render (changing the this.state.user object). At this point the form unmount and I get this error

```js
TypeError: _this4.state.userNotify is undefined
```

I can't find a similar situation on Google. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It appears your state does not contain "userNotify". Take a look at your state; for instance log it out in the render. Check whether it indeed doesn't contain userNotify.

Comment: I set ' this.state = {userNotify:{} } ' in the constructor and it reports errors correctly using that state object. I'll try logging that to the render a little later. I'm away from a computer for the day. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, I figured out the problem. I was returning a correctly structured error object from an ajax request within the component class but when there was no error, I was setting this.userNotify equal to an undefined object by accident (badly structured JSON response). My question now is why wasn't I warned about setting userNotify equal to an undefined object at the time (the line number) where I was doing so? Instead node was reporting the error at the line where I assigned the property within the clone Element function. Why is that?